# Converting cryptocurrencies on Binance with python-binance api

Tags: python, binance, cryptocurrency

Is it possible to convert cryptocurrencies with python-binance api? I was looking at `create_order` function, but it seems to only enable spot trades.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of methods you can use with spot and futures.
check documentation: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#

for example:

after the install python-binance

```
from binance.client import Client
api_key='api_key'
api_secret='secret_key'

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
client.futures_create_order()
```